# Force blazor to run code on browser in javascript

Tags: blazor

I am writing a C# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Blazor Server app.

Here is one of my razor page:

```
@page "/myurl"

<p>Variable1: @var1</p>

<button @onclick="test_event">Test</button>

@code {
    private int var1 = 0;

    private void test_event()
    {
        // This code is runned on server side
        var1 = /* Long calculation */;  // I want to run this line on browser, in javascript

        var1 = var1 + 1; // This calculation is basic and can be runned on server
    }
}
```

As you can see, test_event C# code is runned on server.

Now, let's suppose i have very big calculation to do. Is there a way to tell C# to translate this line of code into javascript and run it on the browser.

My goal is to avoid to load my server and make calculations on each browser.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Blazor WASM, all run in the browser

Comment: Yes but i can’t choose which Line is executed on browser and which one is executed on server

Comment: Create WebApi on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sadly not.
But you can implement it in JS and call the function via JS interop, see here: [Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
Alternatively would have to use a Blazor-Webassembly Project, which runs on the browser. Blazor-Webassembly will be released this month and the release candidate is already available.

Otherwise, but I don't even know if it works under .Net Core, you could use a C#/JS transpiler like [Bridge](https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge)